# What happens to a thread if I don't call the End... method?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, webservice-client

I have a web service reference proxy class with generated asynchronous methods. I call a method using BeginMethodName. I can pass a callback function and then in the callback function call EndMethodName to get results or an exception. But what will happen to the parallel thread if I don't call EndMethodName? I've tried to monitor the app using debugger and it looks like those threads get killed any way. But that might be due to their master thread being killed. But what if master thread won't get killed? Will those parallel proxy threads be killed by some timeout? I don't need to know the result of the method call, and the method call is OneWay any way.

Answer (score 1):

When a thread finishes executing it will close on its own.

"It is not necessary to retain a reference to a Thread object once you have started the thread. The thread continues to execute until the thread procedure is complete." - MSDN

Additionally,  if it is a background thread then it will close abruptly whenever the master thread is killed.  If it is a foreground thread then the application will wait until the foreground thread is finished before closing.

By default threads are foreground.  If you want to ensure that the thread closes when your master thread is killed then set the IsBackground property = true.

Comment: But where are the exception and results stored if the thread is killed?